# The regression line don't pass through the cloud of points

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression

---

The code is this one down here.

```
altura <- read.table("altura.txt", header=T, quote="\"")
altura <- cbind(altura, altura$Esposa/altura$X.Marido, altura$X.Marido/altura$Esposa)
is.data.frame(altura)
names(altura) <- c("marido","esposa","r1","r2")
with(altura,plot(marido~esposa))
g1 <- lm(altura$esposa~altura$marido)
summary(g1)
abline(g1$coefficients)
abline(0,1,lty=5)
with(altura,plot(esposa~marido))
g2 <- lm(altura$marido~altura$esposa)
summary(g2)
abline(g2$coefficients)
abline(0,1,lty=5)
cor(altura$marido,altura$esposa)
```

The simple regression line doesn't pass through the cloud of points. The abline is using the correct intercepts from the summary function. This is not the first time that happens. As you see, at both graphs I'm this problem. One line passes over the points, the other below.

Comment: Please anyone can help? The coefficients i think ware calculated wrong can that be possible? Is it normal?

Comment: Can you either post your data or a picture of the graphs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see: Your g2 model: 
`g2 <- lm(altura$marido~altura$esposa` should go with `with(altura,plot(marido~esposa))` you have it with `with(altura,plot(esposa~marido))`

e.g

```
set.seed(1021)

x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 3*x + rnorm(100)
m1 <- lm(y~x)
plot(y~x)
abline(m1$coefficients)
m2 <- lm(x~y)
abline(m2$coefficients, col = 'red')
```

You are plotting the red line where you want the black one and vice versa.

Comment: unfortunately , this does not seem to work if you have a categorical predictor, wonder why: x <-(rep(c(1,0),13))# creando un factor categórico
y <- 3*x+rnorm(26,5,1)
x=as.factor(x)
levels(x)=c("a","b")
plot(y~x, pch=19, col= "blue",cex=1.3)
mod2=lm(y~x)
abline(mod2$coefficients,col="red", cex=1.3)